# Run Configuration: Maven & Tomcat together in Debug Mode

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a run configuration that builds many maven projects, then it deploys to tomcat.  When I am in debug mode, sometimes a maven project will fail to build.

I would want to restart the entire run configuration again in debug mode.  However, the debug mode is greyed out.  The only way to fix this is to restart Intellij.

Am I doing something wrong or could I do something that will enable the debug mode again?

Comment: What do you mean by 'run configuration'? Is it a configuration that executes a maven build? Or is it an app-server config that performs a make/build before the artifacts are deployed?

Comment: 'run configuration' is an Intellij drop down where you could string many jobs together to run one after the other.  I have it run dependent projects to the main project I am interested in deploying.  With 'run configuration', you could then choose to deploy your war file after all of your projects have built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this type of issue, I always run without debug mode and attach a `remote` debugging session when I need it.

Comment: what do you use for a remote debugger?  Could you give me a link on how to do this?

Comment: If you open your run configurations, and click the + at the top left, you should see `Remote` as on of the options (for me it's nearly at the bottom of the list). This creates a run configuration for a remote debugging session. The options are pretty much defaulted correctly, but you should provide your particular debugging port (and host if the server isn't running on your local machine). You should then alter your startup script for maven to run with support for remote debugging -- the run dialog tells you which options you need. I always run the server outside Idea, and just deploy to it.

Comment: This has helped.  Thank you.  I, also, use DCEVM to do dynamic code modification on tomcat.  So I need to decide which one if preferable because I haven't found a way to do both at the same time.